# Azure Node.js Easy API Middleware

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-mobile-services

I've got an Azure node.js app. I wanted to add 'multer' middleware, for dealing with file uploads, to only one POST easy-api.

For example, I have the file `./api/upload-files.js`, which is supposed to look something like this:

```
module.exports = {
    "post" : async (req, res, next) => {
        // ...
    }
};
```

And I can quite easily add the multer middleware to the `./app.js` file, where the express app is initialized:

```
const multer = require('multer');
app.post('*', multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage() }).any());
```

But if I don't want to add multer middleware to *every* post endpoint, but just to the one in `./api/upload-files.js`, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

### Original comment

This is something related with the way you are instanciating the express instance in your app.

If you do not wish to use the `multer` middleware for some request you can just use the function you want in the request itself, avoiding to call the multer function when passing the arguments to the request method.

One example for a get endpoint:

```
app.get('/getrequest', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Someone made a get request to your app');
})
```

One example for a post endpoint:

```
app.post('/postrequest', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Someone made a POST request to your app');
})
```

Keep in mind that you add or remove middleware functions in express this way.

```
app.use('/user/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('I am a middleware!')
  next()
}, function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('I am another function')
  next()
})
```

[Here are the docs](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

### Edit

Could maybe this code adapt to your usecase?

```
app.post('*', checkUseMulter);

function checkUseMulter(req, res, next) {
    if (['/mypathwithoutmulter', '/myotherpath'].includes(req.path)) {
        return next();
    }

    return multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage() }).any();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm actually aware of this pattern, but as far as I can tell it does not apply directly to the way Azure Easy APIs are created. As you can see, instead of saying `app.post('/api/upload-files`, middleware, func)`, instead you can only do `module.exports = {"post": func}` -- it's less obvious to me how to apply middleware here

Comment: Your edit may work. It's not...nice, like I don't like it and I'd prefer to do it. However, I don't know if you tried that code or not, but my intuition tells me that you can't just return `multer.any()` like that in that context - you maybe have to do something like `multer(...).any()(req, res, next)` rather than returning anything, since `any()` just returns a function and that function won't be called by just returning it.

Comment: I don't know much about the multer lib, but I assumed that it was taking the req, res, next params, and doing the middleware function on it. You might be right that this is not the best approach but, in some other issues it's the typical approach, so that's why I added it here. I can't help anymore from now on, good luck and I'll keep a look in here to see if it did get fixed